# Generic parameter S could not be inferred

Tags: ios, swift, string, encoding, buffer

Generic parameter S could not be inferred.

```
 var buff:[Int8] = [Int8](repeating:0,count:16)
 ...
 var addr = String(bytes: buff, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

[How it seems in xCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOznB.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string/1779872-init), `buff` needs to be of type S where `S : Sequence, S.Iterator.Element == UInt8`. So you need it to be an array of UInt8's instead of Int8's

```
import Foundation

var buff:[UInt8] = [UInt8](repeating:0,count:16)
var addr = String(bytes: buff, encoding: .utf8)
```